# Post params not read when header is passed in volley android

Tags: android, post, parameters, header, android-volley

When i remove header from code, params posted are read. But when i include headers, my params are not taken in volley.

Here is my code.

```
StringRequest mystring = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e("HttpClient", "success! response: " + response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("HttpClient", "error: " + error.toString());
            }
        })
{
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("locale", localeName);
        return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //my headers here
       return params;
    }
};
queue.getCache().clear();
queue.add(mystring);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may you have to debug the HTTP request, because the below code is working on me.

```
StringRequest post = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, baseURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Log.d(TAG, ""+error.getMessage()+","+error.toString());
    }
}){
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("id", "28");
        params.put("value", "1");

        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        headers.put("token", "31das32basdxzxf00");
        return headers;
    }
};


    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(post);
```

Comment: its just instance of Volley here it is

Comment: headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); changing my header to this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static String SIGNATURE_KEY="klk123n138921bnejkwq_as3e3";

public static final String TAG = AppController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}